# How can I use Pattern and Matcher with StringBuffer or char[] types instead of String?

Tags: java, string, matcher, stringbuffer

How can I use a method like this

```
private boolean respectPattern(String password) {
  Pattern passwordPattern = Pattern.compile(
    "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[.@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*?&.]{8,}$",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = passwordPattern.matcher(password);
  return matcher.find();
}
```

If I replace `password` type with `StringBuffer` or `char[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `matcher()` in class `java util.regex.Pattern` takes a single parameter whose type is [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) which is an interface. According to the *javadoc*, there are several implementing classes, including `StringBuffer`. If none of the existing implementations are suitable for your needs, you can always write your own implementation.

For example, using a [CharBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html)

```java
CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(11);
cb.put(new char[]{'S','e','c', 'r', 'e', 't', ' ', 'P', 'a', 's', 's'});
Pattern passwordPattern = Pattern.compile(
                "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[.@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*?&.]{8,}$",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = passwordPattern.matcher(cb);
```

Comment: Instead of copying the `char[]` array into a new `CharBuffer`, you can simply use `CharBuffer.wap(array)` to get a *view* to the array. Especially with sensitive information, you should avoid creating additional copies.

Answer (score 1):

> if I replace password type with StringBuffer or char[]?

**If you replace password type with `StringBuffer`:**

Use as it is i.e. the following will compile successfully and work as intended:

```
private boolean respectPattern(StringBuffer password) {
    Pattern passwordPattern = Pattern.compile(
            "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[.@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*?&.]{8,}$",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = passwordPattern.matcher(password);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

**If you replace password type with `char[]`:**

Use `passwordPattern.matcher(String.valueOf(password));`

Comment: I don't want my password gets converted to String type, so I don't wan't to use .toString method nor String.valueOf

Comment: You can do also `""+password` when password is a StringBuffer thanks to Java's autoboxing, but to be honest I'd go for @arvind-kumar-avinash solution as it's cleaner. May I ask why you don't want to use `.toString()` or `valueOf()`?

Comment: I don't want my password to be stored in String constant pool, because String are immutable

Comment: There is no need to call `toString()` or `String.valueOf(…)`. You can simply pass the `StringBuffer` instance to `matcher(…)` directly.

Comment: @Ob-la-di strings do not get stored in a constant pool, unless they truly are compile-time constants (or were added explicitly).

Comment: Thanks, @Holger for the valuable feedback. I've updated the answer to incorporate the same.